# Simplest Dataloader fails when num_workers>0

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

The following very simplistic Dataloader  works, when `num_workers=0`, but fails with unexpected Runtime Error as soon as I increase to 1: `RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid(s) 8248) exited unexpectedly`
My project is bigger but I could cut down the problem to this minimalistic example.

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

class DummyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, num_samples):
        self.num_samples = num_samples

    def __len__(self):
        return self.num_samples

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        try:
            # Generate random data for features and labels
            # Features: shape (6, 64, 64), random float values
            # Labels: shape (64, 64), random binary values
            features = torch.randn(6, 64, 64)
            labels = torch.randint(0, 2, (64, 64))
            return features, labels
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Error at index {idx}: {e}')
            raise

# Usage:
num_samples = 1000
dummy_dataset = DummyDataset(num_samples)

# Create a DataLoader
dummy_dataloader = DataLoader(dummy_dataset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, num_workers=1)

# Try to fetch a batch of data
data_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(dummy_dataloader))
print(data_batch.shape, labels_batch.shape)
```

I checked the Manual but couldn't find any solution. The general setup on my computer is working and even the following example gives no error with 4 workers:

```
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=32, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)

# Try to get a batch of data
data, labels = next(iter(trainloader))
print(data.shape, labels.shape)
```

Therefore I think the problem is part of my implementation. On the other hand, google colab does not raise problems here. And so it might be a problem of my environment as well which I can't identify.

Versions:

- Python: 3.11.5
- torch: 2.0.1

I'll be glad to provide more information to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: It is up to the platform and many other random factors if and why this snippet might work or not work for you.

Details:
According to many posts and some description about the specifics of pytorch's way of multiprocessing with `spawn()` (Win, Mac) and `fork()` (*nix) it is an open issue. There are many ideas how to tackle the problem with changing parameters. But IMHO these non-solutions but lucky situations where it somehow worked at the end. I personally suspect a timing problem deep inside the multiprocessing part and guess many users come to this problem but can't tackle it down. In my case I thought about a not thread-safe IO operation (I wanted to access GeoTiff files originally).
Here are some sources which might be interesting or helpful for you:

- [Dataloader worker exited unexpectedly while running on Visual Studio. But runs okay on Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67258047)
- [PyTorch RuntimeError: DataLoader worker (pid(s) 15332) exited unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60101168)
- https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#platform-specific-behaviors
- https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/12831